# How to use a custom Express server with Ember CLI?

Tags: ember-cli

I'm using Ember CLI 0.0.36. When I run `ember server` in my project folder, my understanding is that a server buried in some Brocoli process gets started. However I would like to program a custom Express server and have my app point to that Node.js code for its backend. How would I go about doing that within the Ember CLI framework?

UPDATE:

Following [@user3155277's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24427664/2081402), I added an adapter file like so:

**app-name/app/adapters/application.js**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({ namespace: 'api' });
```

I created an Express server that I put at the root of my app:

**app-name/server.js**:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    path = require("path");

app.get("/api/test", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        hello: "world"
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8147);
```

In the Ember app, my index route is defined as so:

**app-name/app/routes/index.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON("/api/test").then(function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

On the command line I then start the server like so:

```
ember serve --proxy http://localhost:8147/
```

I get the following error:

```
version: 0.0.35-master-86abdb11ba
Proxying to http://localhost:8147/
object is not a functionTypeError: object is not a function
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.start (D:\ember-cli\lib\tasks\server\express-server.js:41:43)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (D:\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:40:23)
    at Class.module.exports.Command.extend.run (D:\ember-cli\lib\commands\serve.js:35:18)
    at Class.Command.validateAndRun (D:\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:74:15)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (D:\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:33:20)
    at tryCatch (D:\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp\-internal.js:163:16)
    at invokeCallback (D:\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp\-internal.js:172:17)
    at publish (D:\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp\-internal.js:150:13)
    at flush (D:\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\commonjs\rsvp\asap.js:51:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)Livereload server on port 35729
```

Comment: Ember-cli is iterating so fast however 0.0.39 makes this less painful. Generate a api-stub from command line and boom. you just have to var express = require('express') but in 0.0.40 will not have too. I had the same problems with api-stubs prior

Comment: Hey @elrick, I waited for 0.0.40 to come out but I'm still quite confused about how to set up the whole thing. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple with Ember CLI 0.0.40:

Create folder structure

```
ember new my-app
```

Go into the newly created folder

```
cd my-app
```

Generate api-stub* (see update)

```
ember generate api-stub my-server
```

This latter command creates a `server` folder with an `index.js` file and a `routes` folder with a `my-server.js` file.

Open `my-server.js` file and you see:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var express = require("express");
    var myServerRouter = express.Router();
    myServerRouter.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.send({my-server:"something"});
    });
    app.use("/api", myServerRouter);
};
```

All you need to do then is to change that file. If the Ember app makes calls to `/api/hamsters` and `/api/project`, edit as follows:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var express = require("express");
    var myServerRouter = express.Router();
    myServerRouter.get("/hamsters", function(req, res) {
        res.send({ ... });
    });
    myServerRouter.get("/project", function(req, res) {
        res.send({ ... });
    });
    app.use("/api", myServerRouter);
};
```

To start the server (from project's root):

```
ember server
```

Make sure you have updated node.js to the latest version as well.

---

#### Updates

As of Ember CLI 0.0.41 ([via this PR](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/1530)) `api-stub` has been renamed `http-mock`.

Comment: As of Ember CLI 0.0.41 ([via this PR](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1530)) `api-stub` has been renamed `http-mock`.

Comment: Just note, from the ember-cli docs: `Note: Mocks are just for development and testing. The entire /server directory will be ignored during ember build.`

Comment: Do people use Mirage now to test?

Answer (score 3):

I started playing with ember cli so i'm not sure but i found the following:
https://github.com/dockyard/ember-cli-plus-backend/tree/rails-served-html/frontend/api-stub
Basically you should proxy your express server to the same port as your ember-cli (so then you don't have to deal with jsonp issue)

> Set the method to 'proxy' and define the proxyURL to pass all API requests to the proxy URL.

UPDATE:

1.Generate adapter `ember generate adapter application`

2.Make api namespace - fill the created file with the following code:

export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'api'
});

3.Start the server with `ember serve --proxy http://localhost:1337/` (this will proxy all your request to localhost:4200 to 1337

4.Make routes in your express app prefixed by /api

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try and let you know how it goes. But, before that, and this might be a silly question, do you know how to deal with that when going into production? Using a proxy sounds like a hack.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestions. See my edited question with the issues I encountered.

Comment: Please try using the latest version im using 0.0.37
For the hacking question this proxy workaround is only for developing you should use files in dist directory for a production server served by your express app.

Comment: I made a similar buildpack for using a Node backend rather than Rails. I use a proxy during development, but this in production (which doesn’t proxy anything). https://github.com/andrewbranch/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-ember